# How to install nodejs version 6 in Linux Mint 18.3 sylvia

Tags: node.js

I need to install Nodejs version 6 in Linux Mint 18.3 sylvia.
I already tried running this:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -`

But result in errors like:

```
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Linux Mint 18.3 _Sylvia_ - Release amd64 
20171124/dists/xenial/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt- 
cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be 
used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/**DISTRIBUTION**/main/ 
binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Anyone have Idea to install this? Thanks

Comment: this is not for stack overflow, u should ask this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Installing Node.js is pretty straightforward using Linuxbrew, the Linux port of Homebrew. It handles downloading, unpacking, compiling, and installing Node on your system. After you have Linuxbrew installed, the whole process should only take you a few minutes.

Open up your terminal and type **brew install node**.

Sit back and wait. Homebrew has to download some files, compile and install them. But that’s it.

Answer (score -1):

try to install the current version
[10.15.3 LTS](https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.3/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64.tar.xz)